# Group by query django

Tags: django, group-by, django-views

Can I obtain something like this in Django?
Teacher has multiple evaluations, this evaluations has multiples "grades", so, I would like to obtain every evaluations given by each teacher.
Until now, I can obtain every grade by every teacher, but I would like to group this grade by teacher.

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot

PD:

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
    application = models.ForeignKey('application.Application')
    evaluator = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Grade(models.Model):
    evaluation = models.ForeignKey(Evaluation)
```

Comment: Can you add your relevant models?

Comment: Where is `Teacher` relationship ?

Comment: Sorry, Teacher is User

Comment: and How you are expecting the output? `QuerySet`s format?

Comment: Yep, That would be perfect

Answer (score -1):

```
def grades_of_the_teacher(teacher):
    evaluations = teacher.evaluation_set.all()
    return Grade.objects.filter(evaluation__in=evaluations)
```